# deriving clause with arbitrary "Constraint aliases"?

Tags: haskell

For example, this declaration with `deriving`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, ConstraintKinds #-}
import Data.Data (Data)
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)

type Constraints a = (Show a, Eq a, Ord a, Data a, Typeable a)
data A = A deriving (Constraints)
```

errors with:

```
Illegal deriving item ‘Constraints’
```

Which makes sense given http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html

I write `deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Data, Typeable)` for most of my types. It might be nice to export standard "constraint aliases", i.e. any type of kind `* -> Constraint`. Given, of course, that the constraints in the constraint tuple are all the right arity, have an empty "minimal complete definition", etc.

Is there any proposal for this? How hard would it be? Are there alternatives?

Comment: In terms of a proposal, if it even exists, which I doubt, it probably is very low on the list of things to do, especially since the set of classes you can derive normally is not that large. If you really want to avoid writing out each class every time, you can use Template Haskell to generate standalone deriving declarations.

Comment: yeah I considered that, but then you have Template Haskell's problems of longer compilation, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is no proposal for this. It wouldn't be too hard, but I suspect it wouldn't get a lot of traction. Not only could you use template haskell to generate standalone deriving declarations as a comment suggests, but you could macro-expand to your desired clause using CPP if you really want.

Comment: https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/597